# Asset Catalogue compiler warning: a 76x76@2x app icon is required for iPad apps targeting IOS 7.0 and later

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I've been having this warning for ages, and I just can't seem to get rid of it.

The warning is:

```
/Images.xcassets: A 76x76@2x app icon is required for iPad apps targeting iOS 7.0 and later
```

I've tried completely replacing the asset catalogue with a brand new one, and copying in ones which work on other projects. I've even tried simply not using asset catalogues, but I can't seem to shake this warning.

I can't see any reason as to why it's appearing, especially when I do have a 152x152 app icon in there.

Note, I'm trying to do an icon for iPad IOS 7.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you added a imaged named "AppIcon76x76@2x.png" ?

Comment: Where specifically should I have added it?

Comment: drag an imaged named "AppIcon76x76@2x.png" in the Images.xcassets http://i.imgur.com/2sReh2X.png

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't seem to solve the warning.

Answer (score 48):

Alex's answer didn't work for me when targeting environments below 7.0, but did prompt me to look at the utilities panel, if you open it you'll see checkbox options for "iOS 6.1 and prior sizes".  Check this on to reveal the missing icon assets.

[image: XCode 5 Utilities Panel to reveal additional image asset options]

Answer (score 26):

Oh... It's a pain.

You have to set enough width for Xcode and you will see all images assets.

[image: Xcode Images.xcassets]

Comment: UI fail from Apple on this one.

Comment: @buildsucceeded Big time. This is rather stupid especially since its from Apple. A company which supposedly puts design above all else. lol

Answer (score 9):

I was having this same problem. Made sure that the Attributes Inspector for AppIcon had iPad unchecked, and made sure that Deployment Info -> Devices was set for iPhone, then hit Shift-Cmd-K to clean. Went right away, then I was able to add them and the deployment setting again like normal. Worked great.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem, i was missing icon for iOS 6.1 and earlier. So i found a [important guide on app icon by apple you can found it here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html).

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Edit: Your name of icon must be same os of apple icon naming mentioned on the link.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 9/Swift 4**

Same issue here. I only had a 152x152 icon in the "iPad App iOS 7-11 76 pt @2x" slot and I solved by adding a 76x76 icon in the @1x slot.