# Xcode is complaining that I need an icon for an iPhone 7 but there is nowher

Tags: ios, xcode, image

I am so confused!!!! I've created an app which works great on all IOS phones and iPads but Xcode is complaining that I need an icon for iPone 7. It's stating that it wants an icon of 60x60@2x. OK....lets add it...I've gone into Assets--> Appicon and there is no place to add the icon Xcode is complaining about. On the iPad the icon is visible but on the iPhone 7 it's blank:

As you can see from below there is nowhere to add it:

[Where do i put the image?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfaBw.png)

This is the warning I'm getting:

Blah/Blah/Blah/Assets.xcassets: A 60x60@2x app icon is required for iPhone apps targeting iOS 7.0 and later

Because I've got an old iPad which cannot be updated above IOS 9.3, I'm wondering if this is the indue?

I've set the Deployment Info like so:

[Deployment info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPmJ2.png)

Any help you can give will be appreciated, and I will take abuse if it's something simple, but being team players I'm sure that won't happen :)

My name is Alex by the way and I've only been coding in Swift for 3 months, so go easy on me :)

Alex

Comment: You make it tougher than you should to "go easy" when you fill in pieces with "Blah/Blah/Blah". That said, my best idea for you is to use one of **several** icon generators. They are basically free. At the risk of giving too much info - search the app store (Mac App Store that is) for "Asset Catalog Creator". That's what I use - paid for the IAP - In-App Purchase if you care - and you get all you need for icons. (And yes, Alex, I'm going easy on you.)

Answer (score 0):

You have no iPhone icons in your assets at all according to your screenshot. It looks like you originally created the app for iPad and went universal later?

With the app icons open in your asset catalogue, open the inspector on the right hand side (see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20598572/2466193) for an image - different problem, same solution) and check the empty boxes to get spaces to add appropriate app icons.